# What is a Design pattern for "Remember Me" that forces user to explicitly choose "remember" or "do not remember?

Tags: design-patterns, password

We have a very nontechnical user base.
We provide a "Remember Me on this computer" option (checked by default) but perhaps it should not be checked by default.

However, I want to make sure they have look at it an decided whether to check it.

Options I"ve considered:

---

[ Login  ]

( )  *Remember me* on this computer

( )  *I* will *remember* my Email and Password

//both are initially unselected, so they must select one.
*Downside:*  They'll probably not notice the options and need to be told "pick one of these"

---

I could also do it like:

---

Choose:
( )  *Remember me* on this computer

( )  *I* will *remember* my Email and Password

[ Login  ]

---

Or I could just provide two buttons:

[ **Remember me** on this computer and **LOGIN** ]

[ **I** will **remember** my Email and Password. **LOGIN**]

---

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be 110% sure that your users are seeing it, then just force a prompt to continue. (If you want them to actually read it, you can try making it memorable / tongue in cheek.)

They hit LOGIN -> Prompt:

Would you like us to remember who you are?

[I never remember my login, please remember it for me!]
[I like typing my login info every time!]

(Disclaimer: We will only ask you this once.)

I would definitely use two buttons, each with a clearly marked choice.

Don't let them continue on without choosing one. If they aren't tech savvy. (Old People) then make it come up dead center, and use big hard to miss text.

In my experience designing for people who barely understand technology the less you obfuscate the better. They don't think to go looking in settings menus. Also keep in mind browsers will often times pop up with 'Would you like us to remember this password.' so chances are they are used to these pop ups already.